# Как остановить запущеный процес на Heroku

Tags: heroku

У меня есть запущенный процесс выглядит так:

```
MacBook-Pro-kirya:TelegramBot kirya$ heroku ps
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== worker (Free): java -jar build/libs/TelegramBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (1)
worker.1: up 2017/06/28 14:08:56 +0300 (~ 2s ago)
```

после чего я запускаю `heroku ps:stop worker.1` и вижу что процесс изменил статус

```
=== worker (Free): java -jar build/libs/TelegramBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (1)
worker.1: idle 2017/06/28 14:11:45 +0300 (~ 4s ago)
```

но через несколько секунд процесс снова запущен:

```
=== worker (Free): java -jar build/libs/TelegramBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (1)
worker.1: up 2017/06/28 14:12:13 +0300 (~ 30s ago)
```

Как я могу остановить процесс полностью, так что бы он не перезапускался пока я сам этого не сделаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это должно остановить полностью

```
heroku ps:scale worker=0
```

Comment: сработало, спасибо!

Comment: К слову, для web process type пишется похожая команда:
heroku ps:scale web=0